# How do I format XML ampersands for XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt, rss

I am attempting to transform the XML I'm retrieving from an RSS feed. This links within this feed contain ampersands which, as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150333/xml-containing-link-throws-error-in-visual-studio-when-running-xslt-debugger), are causing the transform to bomb. (Replacing all of the "&" with `"&amp;"` in the RSS's XML allows the transform to complete.)

Can anyone recommend a good approach for reformatting the RSS XML, or is there no good way to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML you need to use `&amp;` to escape an ampersand. XSLT is XML so the same rule applies.